# Confusion related to virtual machine in nand2tetris

Tags: memory, stack, virtual-machine, nand2tetris

So while doing a course on nand2tetris I got stuck in this question.[image: credits: Coursera][image: credits: Coursera]

Basically this question is related to building a virtual machine. The virtual machine is quite similar to JVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 main parts to consider here:

1. `call foo 2` : this instruction tells vm to call funcion `foo` that takes 2 arguments ( which should be pushed on top of the stack before this call ). 
   Calling any function means that you should take these steps as follow: push return address on top of stack (SP++), then push LCL, ARG, THIS,THAT ( SP+4). At this point SP should equal 310.
2. `function foo 4` : this is NOT the first instruction in function `foo`, but still it has an effect on SP as this means that function`foo` has 4 local variables. And these variables must be located somewhere. Where? On top of the stack. This means that before first 'real' instruction of `foo` gets executed, we must push 4 values onto the stack. What values? Well - according do vm specification it should be `0`'s, resulting in local variables being initiated to 0. This also means that we increase SP for every local variable ( SP + 4)

This leads to conclusion that SP, after calling `foo` but before executing 1st instruction of this function will have value of 314.